# Should container component in React never have styles?

Tags: reactjs, redux

It is mentioned in many articles that Container Components are used to fetch data and dispatch actions. Presentation Components are used to define *how* that data is rendered.
It also suggests that container components should never have their own style.

Here's the question: 
I have 3 presentation components, all consumed by 1 container component. The container component fetches the data and provides the required data to each presentation component.

May I wrap and style the presentation components in the container component for styling purposes. For instance, I'd like to style the presentation components to use render in a grid?

Comment: Container components should never have any styles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Nest your presentation components in a parent that isn't a container.
- Add styling to this parent

Job done.

Comment: Thanks, the parent here is a presentation, which means I need to add an extra container to presentation. May I simply let the parent be a container, fetch the data and set some layout style so that I can have one level removed, as container -> (view,view,view). I cannot see the benefit of container -> view -> (view, view, view)

Comment: Did you come up with clean solution @andrew?

Comment: @AndrewZhang, I both kind of agree with you, but also see where there might be confusion. There are some instances where having an arbitrary view just to provide a couple of wrapper styles is a little obtuse. But think of it like you have three `tile` components. This wrapping component is really just the "grid view" of these "tiles". In the same vein, you could potentially have another wrapping component that stacked these tiles vertically, or maybe create a polymorphic wrapper that can be a tile grid _or_ a stack. Perhaps this wrapper can use different tiles. Benefits come from necessity.

Comment: @Nicolas I think above comment really make sense. 'Benefits come from necessity'.